# I have a blog table. Want count as status wise

Tags: mysql

Structure of table :

```
CREATE TABLE `blogs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `blog` text,
  `status` enum('published','draft','trash') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Want a query to display result as follows :

```
published   draft    trash
-----------------------------
   3          5         1 
-----------------------------
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum(status = 'published') as published,
       sum(status = 'draft') as draft,
       sum(status = 'trash') as trash
from blogs
```